# XAML: Hyperlink to another ViewPage

Tags: javascript, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am developing a WinRT application and was wondering if i could link a Hyperlink tag to a JavaScript function or be able to call the view page with NavigateUri? Or if it is possible to use interaction triggers that call the JS by a command.

==Update==
I have been testing different xaml tags from hyperlink to hyperlinkbutton. HyperlinkButton seems to appear and is clickable. it is just the on click function that doesn't seem to get called...

```
 <HyperlinkButton Grid.Row="1"  Click="__Title__.OnBuildingClick" Content="Buildingoo"/>


 <HyperlinkButton Grid.Row="1"  Click="__Title__.OnBuildingClick" Content="Buildingoo" ?
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="ClickHyperlink">
              <behaviors:EventToScriptBehavior Command="__Title__.OnBuildingClick" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
          </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </HyperlinkButton>
```

these are the 2 approaches i have taken. The functino onBuildingClick is only an alert msg but it doesnt get called..

Comment: To give you he right answer, you;re WinRT app is Html5/javascript based?

Comment: By Definition XAML based apps are limited to executing code complied from C# or C++. The only place where interactions between XAML and Javascript are possible is inside a C#(or C++)/XAML app that makes use of a WebView control. Is this your intention?

Comment: Yep spot on. We have an online soultion explorer that uses xaml and js. Though it is programmed with c#

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the webView has a predefined name "currentWebView":

```
<WebView x:Name="currentWebView" ... />
```

You can access the control from the codebehind using its name, and then tell the web view to search the DOM for a javascript function by name, and invoke it if the function exists.

To invoke a method by name you will use the C# Method "InvokeScript" and pass 2 parameters:

Param 1: Name of Javascript function

Param 2: Comma Separated List of Arguments in order of Javascript Signature

```
currentWebView.InvokeScript("nameOfFunction", "myFirstparam, secondParam, thridParam");
```

Additionally, in order to allow the XAML UI to respond to the Javascript event your Javascript code must call

```
nameOfFunction(param1, param2, param3){
    window.external.notify("This content will be accessible in the next steps NotifyEventArgs e.Value property.")
};
```

and in the last piece of wiring up the ability to respond to Javascript from C#, you must apply an event handler in the C# codebehind to allow the XAML to be notified what is going on inside the WebControl

```
// In the Constructor / OnLoaded/ OnNaviagtedTo Event of the code behind
currentWebView.ScriptNotify +=  new NotifyEventHandler(currentWebView_ScriptNotify);

... then later in the class

private void currentWebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
   //can access the value included in the notification 
   var notification = e.Value;
   someTextblock.Text = notification;
}
```

Putting It Together:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="btnExecuteJavaScript" Grid.Row="1"  Click="btnExecuteJavaScript_Click" Content="Buildingoo"/>

public void btnExecuteJavaScript_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    currentWebView.InvokeScript("OnBuildingClick", "arbitraryParameter, mayNotBeNeeded");
}
```